# Rename all files in a directory with numbers

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone could help me write a PHP script for me that renames all the files in a directory in a sequence.

So...

- DSC_10342.JPG -> 1.JPG
- DSC_10343.JPG -> 2.JPG
- DSC_10344.JPG -> 3.JPG

  and so on.

Comment: In what order should they be sorted before changing the names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my version:

```
// open the current directory (change this to modify where you're looking)
$dir = opendir('.');

$i = 1;

// loop through all the files in the directory
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    // if the extension is '.jpg'
    if (strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'jpg')
    {
        // do the rename based on the current iteration
        $newName = $i . '.jpg';
        rename($file, $newName);

        // increase for the next loop
        $i++;
    }
}

// close the directory handle
closedir($dir);
```

Comment: `pathinfo` is one of the many reasons I love PHP so much.  If you ever wonder while writing PHP, "Is this already done for me?" then answer is usually, "**YES**."  Good luck on your search through the docs, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to rename the files. You can use [this handy script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) to loop through all files in a directory:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo "$file\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Then it's just a matter of looking at the filenames (`$file`) and figuring out what number to give them. If you need more help than that, just tell me and I'll give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$handler = opendir($directory);
$index = 1;
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        rename($directory."/".$file, $directory."/".$index.".JPG");
        $index++;
    }

}
closedir($handler);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using someone's snippet it would look like this:

```
<?php
$path = '.';
$i = 1;
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_file($path.'/'.$file)) {
            $oldname   = $path.'/'.$file;
            $path_info = pathinfo($oldname);
            rename($oldname, $path.'/'.($i++).'.'.$path_info['extension']);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

It will rename files with all extensions and skip directories that may be inside your directory.